# VBA - Cannot return Value from within If Statement inside For Loop

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, for-loop, return

I have a method called "checkConvert" which is supposed to return a String.

I have created a For Loop which at the end of the loop returns a value as checkConvert.  Also, inside that For Loop, I have setup a Case and inside that Case, another For loop with If Statements inside.  Inside those If Statements, I have also tried to return a value as checkConvert, however it does NOT work at all.

```
For i = val To lastColumn_source
    For j = 1 To 3
        Dim cellValue As String
        cellValue = salesSource.Cells(j, i).Value

        Select Case i
            Case 1
                Dim match As Boolean
                match = False                'Default is false.  
                                             'Equating two cells = false.

                For x = 1 To lastRow_check
                    If cellValue = sourceCheck.Cells(x, 1) Then
                        CRMDest.Cells(j, 2) = newName
                        match = True         'Match is found.  Thus, true.
                    End If
                    If x = lastRow_check And match = False Then
                        checkConvert = newName           'Supposed to return
                                                         'value.  Doesn't
                                                         'work.
                        MsgBox checkConvert              'But MsgBox works.
                    End If
                 Next x
            Case 2                                'Several more cases follow.
            Case 13
                 checkConvert = "End of Program."        'Returns String
                                                         'to "end program."
                                                         'This one works.
        End Select

        checkConvert = "Move."                           'This return also
                                                         'works.
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     checkConvert = newName           'Supposed to return
>                                      'value.  Doesn't
>                                      'work.
>     MsgBox checkConvert              'But MsgBox works.
> ```

It looks like you're under the impression that *assigning* a function's return value immediately returns. That's not how VBA works.

You've assigned a return value, but the code keeps running because, well, an assignment is just that: an *assignment*.

If you want to exit the function immediately after setting its return value, you need to do so explicitly:

```
    checkConvert = newName
    Exit Function
```

The return values that "work", only work out of sheer luck. You're assigning the return value inside a loop, and never jumping out of it, so the value that's returned by the function is whatever value `checkConvert` was last assigned to, in the last iteration.

Comment: My God.  Damn.  That makes so much sense.  I'll see what happens if I do "Exit Function."  Thanks so much, Mat's Mug.  Appreciate it.  :)